# How to find and unblock specific ip address in ubuntu server 18.04?

Tags: server

Installed Ubuntu Server 18.04 with Apache2 (domain.com), Samba etc. Also have ownCloud. My network internal IP is 10.0.0.100 and external IP 98.x.x.30. When I try to open my website (domain.com) from my IP 98.x.x.30 it is not working, cloud not working and also I can not connect with ssh. With internal IP (10.0.0.100) everything working file and also from any other IP everything working fine. Problem only with my external IP (98.x.x.30). How can I find and fix it?

File2band not install
Never touched iptables
In ufw everything right

P.S. It happened when I upload a huge file (2Gb) to ownCloud.

Comment: Do you activate port forwarding in your router?

Comment: yes. The router forward ports 80, 443 and 22 to IP 10.0.0.100. As I said couple days ago everything worked fine. Now not. It's looks like the ubuntu block all requests only from my external IP (98.x.x.30)

Comment: - have a look in /etc/hosts.deny
- what is the output of: > sudo iptables -L -v

Comment: /etc/hosts.deny is clean. Nothing denied

Comment: sudo iptables -L -v do not have any drops